# Cardinalidade do índice não atualiza

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, índices, cardinalidade

Eu estou criando um programa que se conecta a um banco de dados MySQL online, e ao iniciá-lo ele cria uma tabela com um índice caso não existir.

Para verificar se está tudo ok estou analisando o banco de dados pelo phpMyAdmin do servidor, mas quando verifico a estrutura da tabela no índice criado pelo programa mostra que a cardinalidade é a mesma quantia de registros existentes na tabela como se nada foi otimizado. Mas se eu crio um novo índice pelo phpMyAdmin a cardinalidade do índice criado pelo programa aparece corretamente com o valor otimizado.

Por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cardinalidade neste contexto é a relação de unicidade dos dados de acordo com a chave do índice. Costuma ser melhor ter cardinalidade alta, ou seja, quanto mais próximo a chave produza valores únicos, melhor. Cardinalidade baixa costuma prejudicar a velocidade e pode até inviabilizar o uso do índice. Exemplos:

- Uma coluna de sexo provavelmente terá cardinalidade 2 (quase a mais baixa possível que é 1, o que indicaria que o campo não está servido para algo útil)
- Uma coluna de ID terá o mesmo número de linhas da tabela (a mais alta possível)
- Índices com chave que gera a mesma combinação de colunas tem mesma cardinalidade

A cardinalidade só vai mudar - por qualquer uma das 3 possíveis operações do SQL - se os dados das colunas envolvidas na chave do índice mudar.

Isto é uma estatística que pode ser usada para decidir se vai usar um índice ou não. Ela não é tão importante assim. Então não precisa estar sempre atualizada, por isto ela só costuma ter uma atualização quando usa-se um `ANALYZE TABLE`. Provavelmente o PHPMyAdmin faz isto sem você saber. Se você deseja forçar a atualização da estatística, faça isto no seu código. Mas pense bem, se não é algo que é feito sempre, porque você deveria?

Está na [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html).